# is it possible to combine two modelmapper as single response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, entity, dto, modelmapper

I want to map two different entity using model mapper with same dto class in spring boot.

My service class code is like this

ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
         modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
List patientConsultationEntity = patientConsultations.findByPatientId(patientId);
        List patientConsultationDtoResponse = Arrays.asList(modelMapper.map(patientConsultationEntity, DetailedConsultationDtoResponse[].class));
        List patientDetailsEntity = patientDetails.findByPatientId(patientId);
        patientConsultationDtoResponse = Arrays.asList(modelMapper.map(patientDetailsEntity, DetailedConsultationDtoResponse[].class));

Problems is it's retuning the latest one only